# How to listen for LLMNR packets on Android?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to listen to LLMNR packet on Android. Is this Possible ? WHat I have tried so far is

```
 private fun runOnSeperateThread() {
        Timber.e("in seprate thread")
        object : Thread() {
            override fun run() {
                try {
                    val socket = DatagramSocket()
                    val buf = ByteArray(1024)
                    val packet = DatagramPacket(buf, buf.size)
                    socket.receive(packet)
                    val text = String(buf, 0, packet.length)

                } catch (ex: Exception) {
                    ex.printStackTrace()
                }
            }
        }.start()
    }
```